# поиск в строке которая задана переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, парсер, методы

задача: из строки которая задана переменной извлечь символы с 15 по 25 (символы в будущем для других строк будут меняться), ищу способом find (), полный код программы прилагается

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import setuptools

name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6]
t2 = lines [-5]
t3 = lines [-6]
# -------- поиск в строке
t1.find ('t1', [1], [2]) #----проблема возникает тут!!!!  
a=t1.find
# --------
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('НА НР') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t4 = line [7:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t4)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
name1: str = input ("Введите имя исходящего файла: ")
f = open (name1, "w+")
# f.write(str(t1 + "\n" +  t2))
f.write ('реквизит верхний// ' + str (a))
f.write ('реквизит нижний// ' + str (t2))
f.write ('дата// ' + str (t3))
f.write ('\nнанр// ' + str (t4))
f.close ()
```

**помогите разобраться с тем как искать подстроку в строке и перекладывать результат в переменную**, изначально как видно программа просто вынимала из документа строку и печатал её в новый документ, теперь хочется печатать с конкретного символа до следующего конкретного символа.

Comment: Так а что вы хотите добиться этой строкой: `t1.find ('t1', [1], [2])`? Непонятно.

Comment: как я предполагаю эта строка должна искать в переменной t1 символы с 1го по 2-й

Comment: Если нужно найти какой то определенный паттерн, то тут нужно использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: @PallNick Символы с 1-го по 2-й это откуда сами то символы берутся, из той же переменной `t1`, она сама в себе свои символы ищет? Я так ничего и не понял. Может примеры какие-то приведёте.

Comment: хорошо тогда я не совсем понимаю что должеy указать в find перед точкой, ищу методом find символы записанные в строке  t1  символы с 1го по 2й.

Comment: Если вам уже известно, что нужные вам символы с первого по второй, то зачем их искать?

Comment: тогда я не понимаю как мне их вписать в конструкцию

Comment: name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6,[1],[2]]
t2 = lines [-5, [1],[2]]
t3 = lines [-6] написав так выпадает ошибка TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

короткий ответ:

```py
s = "Hello world!"
# Срез строки s[индекс_начала_среза:индекс_конца_среза]
# Срез делается по конечный индекс то есть не включительно
print(s[1:4])
# сохранение в переменную
sub_string = s[0:6]
print(sub_string)

# поиск подстроки
start_index = s.find('Hello')
print(start_index)
# .find() возвращает индекс где начинается искомая подстрока
# если вернул -1 значит подстрока не найдена
# то есть если start_index != -1 то подстрока найдена.
```

Но я на вашем месте изучил бы статью по ссылке. Там все очень доходчиво объяснено про то как работать со строками.
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html

Так же, как немного углубитесь, внимательно изучите вот это
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/vstroennye-funkcii.html и настоятельно рекомендую позапускать каждую команду из списка приведенного по этой ссылке. Это то что вы будете использовать и/или видеть очень часто. Понимать как это работает просто необходимо.